ILLEGAL VISA HARAM?
Salaam.
I just wanted to ask, I am in UAE and not employed, (currently on tourist visa for more than a year, we renew it each month and its very expensive). I don't have a job, I have it in a bank, but I left it because of riba, so If I purchase a visa (which is illegal) through a company, where on paper they show to the government I am their employee, and transfer each month a certain amount as salary, but in between us, they will issue me an NOC so I can work anywhere and give that salary back to them each month. Such a setting, would be halal? Or would be classed as deception?
p.s this is very common, and often people to do it to live in uae easily and work wherever they want in a cheap way as compared to getting touritst visas. But I am concerned If am incurring sin or lie or deception with this. Technically I am their employee and hold a visa but I don't have to work ofcourse, this is only a setting for visa.

"Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor. " Putting the background of your question aside, I think this is a valid and deep question. Not all that is haram is illegal by local laws.and not all that is illegal by local laws is haram in general terms.
